# Autoit is not generating a event called after selection of item from list

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, windows-7, automation, autoit

I am using the following code to select an item from list.

```
;Selects a particular Process from the combobox
_GUICtrlComboBox_SelectString($hQueueCombo, $q_index)
```

Usually after selection it should update the value in another box but it is not generating the event attached to this selection. Any Idea what I am missing here. Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the Problem by the following code. Actually we also need to send a notification to window

```
 $hQueueCombo = ControlGetHandle($title, "", $sQueueComboId)
 _GUICtrlComboBox_SelectString($hQueueCombo, $sText)
 $iCode = $CBN_SELCHANGE
 $val = BitShift($iCode, -16)
 $handle = WinGetHandle($title, "")
 _SendMessage($handle, $WM_COMMAND, $val, $hQueueCombo)
```

Hope it helps someone